# How do I use sub-controllers in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, design-patterns

I am learning RoR, and I have a general design issue that I'm trying to work around.  I want to get some input on the answer to make sure I follow some kind of best practice.

I have a page that's made up of 3 subsections, let's call them A, B, and C.  Certain actions cause each of these to refresh via AJAX, so I want to have them each have a controller action that allows any of them to render individually, without the page chrome.

The way I've structured this right now is with a controller that has 4 actions: index, A, B, C

Each of A, B, and C renders its view with layout=>false so I can render just that piece via AJAX when needed.  Then, you have index, which renders some extra stuff along with the view of A, B, and C.

Esentially what I want here are 3 subcontrollers, and a master controller that invokes the subcontrollers as needed.  Or I *think* that is what I want.  What I think I don't want is partial views, because there is some setup I do in the controller for each of A,B,C and I would then have to duplicate the setup code in both the controller for index and the controller for A,B,C.

The code I have in mind is something like this:

my_controller.rb:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
    def index
         @aOutput = A
         @bOutput = B
         @cOutput = C
         render //can use @aOutput, @bOutput, @cOutput in the view
    end

    def A
        render :layout => false    
    end

    def B
        render :layout => false
    end

    def C
        render :layout => false
    end
end
```

This would enable me to now access MyController#index when I want the full page, and MyController#A, etc when I want to re-render the contents of each subsection.

The problem here is if the code is structured like this, you will run into DoubleRender errors when accessing MyController#index.  What is the correct way to approach this kind of thing?  Feel free to blow up any assumptions I made here, with the only requirement being a page that has three sections that can update individually as needed without reloading the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the problem clearly but I think here is what I think your problem is.

- **You want to be able to render only a view without invoking controller action entire.**

  This can be done by using `render :action => :action_name`
- **You want to render some text only for ajax calls**

  Use `respond_to` block in order to achieve this. For example.

  ```
  def whatever_action

    .... # Your action voodoo here

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { ... } # If it a normal HTTP request
      format.js {...} # If it's an ajax or JSON request
    end
  end
  ```

The design that you are proposing has basic flaws like non-adherence to some of the SOLID design principles. I strongly recommend reading a good book on basics of rails.

Comment: This answer isn't terribly helpful. This is a common design: Have a page with some specific HTML chunks within the page that can be replaced via AJAX as needed.  
  
I would imagine each replaceable piece corresponds to a Rails action, and the page as a whole also does.  I just don't see how to properly put the pieces together.  If this is way off or violates some design principle, I would love to know how.  Just randomly static that it violates some acronym and telling me to read a book is not useful at all.  If I wanted to read a book I wouldn't be asking here.

Comment: So you would rather ask questions on stackoverflow _because_ you don't want to read books? Simply googling ["SOLID design Principles"](http://www.google.co.in/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=SOLID+design+principles&qscrl=1) would bring you enough information in the first result to make you understand what I mean. But looks like you don't even want to do that.